# condition coverage not shown as covered / uncovered in sonarqube for C++

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I am using bullseye to generate coverage reports and then the sonar cxx community plugin to import coverage data into SonarQube.

SonarQube does not show which of the condition is covered/uncovered by my test cases when drilling down to source code.
Its shows the percent of condition coverage but does not show which of the conditions are covered/uncovered.

For line coverage its showing which of the functions are covered/uncovered by highlighting the covered ones with a green color and not covered ones with a red color. But same thing its not showing for condition coverage.

How can I see in SonarQube, which of the conditions are covered, and which are not covered?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible.